# Amazon S3: Subdomain mapping with PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How do you make `$s3->get_object_url()` from PHP SDK return:

`http://my-bucket.my-domain.com/example.txt`

instead of

`http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/example.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 doesn't know if a bucketname has a CNAME set up for it, so you'll have to do it yourself. A simple call to `preg_replace` should work fine.

```
$url = preg_replace('@^http://my-bucket\.s3\.amazonaws\.com/@Ui', 'http://my-bucket.my-domain.com/', $url);
```